# Using several loggers with SLF4J facade

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

As far as I understood `SLF4J` allows to change loggers by changing loggers jar's   without changing code. Logger's jar file should be placed in classpath. Pleace, correct me if I'm wrong.

I would like to do logging with `LOG4J` into file plus my custom logger that will log to DB. Is it possible to do so? What is approach?

Currently I do logging like:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class myApp {


    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(myApp.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        logger.info("hello");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Log4J supports logging into a database, why would you make your own?

Comment: Actually I need to log to web service that logs to DB

Comment: Wouldn't that rather be a custom appender? Depending on the actual implementation you use, you can then just define that appender to be used for a particular logger (e.g. myApp) so that everthing logged through that logger is going to the database whereas logs send via different loggers aren't.

Comment: You don't need to do anything, it's rare to come up with a requirement that hasn't been solved already, especially with something like logging. What you might want to do is switch to a more modern logging framework such as `Log4J2` or `Logback`. They implement the `SLF4J` API and they have all the same functionality (and more!).

Comment: Well, I have simple task. I would like to use logger that logs to file and it's logging function has Boolean type additional param and if it is true logs copy on web server. Is that functionality not solved yet?